# Find out the minimum number of moves for jumble game

Tags: java, linear-programming

I want to create a small Jumbler game. I am planning to make this game by using the Java programming language. Following is a small screen shot of the game. I could not find out 
any other sites which contains this game.

[Screen shot of the game at the end of the  page](http://www.searchenginegenie.com/web-design-blog/tag/flash-number-jumbler-game/)

In this game I would like to add to two features.

```
1. Manually solve the problem.
2. Automatically solve the problem.
```

> Manually solve the problem

means we play and find the solution to make the numbers in asendening order

> Visually solve the problem

means the computer graphically shows  the  minimum number of movements required
 for the solution. That means computer graphically shows the movements and identifies the solution with minimum moves.

So how to program this kind of situations?

I searched over internet and got some tutorial which is releated to linear programming. What should I study
in order to solve this kind of problems? I have no idea about how to solve the automatica solution. Please give 
some good tutorials where I can grasp thing easily.

Answer (score 1):

When all you've got is a hammer, everything looks like a nail - so I'd say that this type of problem can be solved using [constraint programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming). But that's just what I've got a little experience in.

Basically, you have a board layout, and there are a small number of valid moves at each 'step'. The aim is to move into a known layout (ascending order).

To do this 'automatically', you need to have the program *search* for a solution path. The steps to do this are something like this:

1. From the *current* layout, determine the valid moves.
2. Calculate the layout after taking each of the valid moves.
3. Check if any of the calculated layouts is the solution; if it is, you're finished.
4. If none of the moves resulted in the solution, work out all the newly-valid moves, and repeat from 1.

You'll have some issues doing this. Firstly, memory constraints (making a bazillion copies of your board layout might not work). Secondly, time/computational constraints (it might take a long, long time to find a solution). There are some things you can do to at least minimize the damage from these issues.

1. Choose a good search method. [Breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) as opposed to [Depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), for example. This will both decrease the time taken to find a solution and decrease the memory requirements.
2. Some moves are "backwards". For example, moving square A to B, and then square B to A (repeating moves). Searching these 'loops' is both pointless and resource-wasting, so you'd want to ensure you don't do that.
3. There is the possibility of symmetries in the search space. I haven't solved your particular problem, and I couldn't give you examples specific to you, but the [n-queens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Solutions_to_the_eight_queens_puzzle) has a nice section on symmetries specific to that problem - it might be worth a read if you're trying to find symmetries in your problem.

That might give you some information, or thoughts to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understand...

minimum occurency and minimum path is a dynamic programming problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

in very very brief, you have to calculate all solutions and show the better one. dynamic programming isn't so simple to understand and develop, but you can try...

however,I suggest you to remeber how you mix it and show that solution...